# Strapi: What would be the best way to create import job?

Tags: javascript, import, cron, strapi

I am very new to the strapi, and I am looking for the best way to create an import job for it.

This job is supposed to be run as a cron and get its data from a temporary database, which means no uploaded files etc.

Strapi is deployed as a docker container to the kubernetes.

There is an example of importer plugin, but it is too huger for has unnecessary frontend while I am looking for something lighter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strapi controller e.g Restaurant is a controller

call it in browser like

`localhost/restaurant/import`

```
module.exports = {
  import: async (ctx) => {
// getRecord(// code goes here)
// strapi.services.restaurant.create(passData)
}}
```

1 - get data e.g from api `https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/`
2 - create strapi record `strapi.services.restaurant.create()`

You can call `localhost/restaurant/import` using cron